# Kendo UI Scheduler binding large array in resource data source

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-scheduler

**Idea of my Project :** I am using Kendo UI Scheduler in my project. My idea is I have large list of employees and I assign each employee working hours for day like John working hours are 10 Am to 4pm from 21 November 2017 to 21 December 2017.

**Issue :** When I bind an array of 1400 records of employee list to resource database in kendoscheduler. It tooks more than 17 seconds to show data on scheduler. Check scheduler code here :

```
scheduler = $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
                    date: new Date(), // The current date of the scheduler        
                    startTime: new Date(new Date().toLocaleDateString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ') + " 8:00 AM"),
                    eventHeight: 30,
                    majorTick: 60,
                    columnWidth: 30,
                    height: 0,
                    editable: false,
                    views: [
                            { type: "timeline", selected: d == null },
                            { type: ThreeDayView, title: "Three day view", selected: d == 3, majorTick: 60 },
                            { type: FiveDayView, title: "Five day view", selected: d == 5, majorTick: 180 },
                            { type: "timelineWeek", title: "Week", selected: d == 7, majorTick: 300 },
                    ],
                    dataSource: schData,
                    group: {
                        resources: ["Employees"],
                        orientation: "vertical"
                    },
                    resources: [
                      {
                          field: "employeeId",
                          name: "Employees",// The field of the Scheduler event which contains the resource identifier.
                          title: "Employees", // The label displayed in the Scheduler edit form for this resource.
                          dataSource: employeeData
                      }
                    ]
                });
```

This **employeeData** is the array which contains 1400 records of employees.So, It hangs my page and took 17-18 second to bind data. Here what my screen look like.
[image: Kendo Ui Scheduler binding data source]

Please help me or suggest any idea so that I can bind large no of data on array without lagging or hanging. I want my scheduler to be very fast load when passing large no of data in resources array.